# How to make Python Configuration File from user input, and insert runs?

Tags: python, file, configuration, configuration-files, configparser

I've got a bunch of Python webdriver runs that I've converted from Selenium IDE.  These runs have 1 or 2 settings that I would like to be able to change using a configuration file that would be created by running a script that collects user input that would set these 2 variables.

Here is my attempt at using the `ConfigParser` module:

```
import ConfigParser

file_path_input = raw_input("Enter path to 'webdriver' directory ex: '/home/user/': ")
print "you entered", file_path_input

url_input = raw_input("Enter url that the application will point to, ex: 172.31.13.56 or vtm55.example.com: ")
print "you entered", url_input

def createConfig(file_path_input):
"""
Create a config file
"""
config = ConfigParser.ConfigParser()
config.add_section("application_settings")
config.set("application_settings", "file_path_to_use", "file_path_input")
config.set("application_settings", "url_to_use", "url_input")
config.set("application_settings", "settings_info",
    "Your application directory is in %(file_path_to_use)s and your application url is %(url_to_use)s")

with open(file_path_input, "wb") as config_file:
    config.write(config_file)
```

The `raw_input()` and `print()` lines work, but the configuration file doesn't appear to be generated at all. Once the file has been created, I'd like to be able to insert the variables `file_path_to_use` and `url_to_use` in my various Python webdriver runs.

Comment: Could you add a few print lines to show what's being executed? Particularly just after the `with(open)` print the file_path_input and config_file vars? Can might show something wrong. Heck, maybe add all the output of when you run it. Alternatively, remove the binary ('b') flag from the open-file statement and try writing it as plain text.

Comment: It does not write what you expect though

Answer (score 1):

1. Your indentation is problematic, particularly in the `createConfig` function.
2. `"file_path_input"` is different from `file_path_input`.
3. Use `'w'` (a normal write) instead of `'wb'` (write bytes).
4. You have `config` and `config_file` backwards - call `write` on `config_file`, then pass it the content you want to write. If you have a list of strings, simply loop through them and write each one with basic file I/O:

   ```
   configs = ['file_path_to_use:' + file_path_input,
   'url_to_use:' + url_input]
   with open(file_path_input, 'w') as config_file:
       for line in configs:
           config_file.write(line + '\n')
   ```

   Sample result:

   ```
   file_path_to_use:/home/user/
   url_input:vtm.example.com
   ```

   I didn't include the `"settings_info"` portion because it's just a recap.
5. You can then `split` or `partition` on `':'` when reading the file back in.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend writing your output as text, not using `ConfigParser`. I've had odd issues with using to *create* config files in the past (though better luck using it to read them). If you convert to write just a text file with standard file-i/o, you have more specificity in how it's written, while still writing it in a format that `ConfigParser` can later read in.

Answer (score 0):

You could scrap using `ConfigParser` and instead create a `.py` file with the variables saved within in the format `KEY=VALUE` in the same way you are creating a `config` file.

Then within your code, write your own function that opens the `.py` file (using `with` syntax, so that it automatically closes the file without `.close()`) and reads it, saving it as a string.

You can then use string manipulation to get the string you want and assign it to a new variable (remember to convert it to the data type you want to use, i.e. `int()` for an integer). Use `type(`) to check the type of the variable if you aren't sure.

Answer (score 0):

It actually starts with lowercase `configparser` and `configparser.ConfigParser()`. 
Please update.